# how to upload an image on ACF with update_field on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, http-post

I have a form, which has an upload (`$_FILES['watch_photo']`) field.

I have looked around and came to put this function together.

It basically takes all relevant information so it is re-usable in the future, it will return an array of the $pid, and URL of the file, when it is done.

The problem is that ACF has not provided much information how to add images to it's fields using `update_field()` http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/update_field/

```
function my_update_attachment($f,$pid,$t='',$c='') {
  wp_update_attachment_metadata( $pid, $f );
  if( !empty( $_FILES[$f]['name'] )) { //New upload
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

    $override['action'] = 'editpost';
    $file = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES[$f], $override );

    if ( isset( $file['error'] )) {
      return new WP_Error( 'upload_error', $file['error'] );
    }

    $file_type = wp_check_filetype($_FILES[$f]['name'], array(
      'jpg|jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',
      'gif' => 'image/gif',
      'png' => 'image/png',
    ));
    if ($file_type['type']) {
      $name_parts = pathinfo( $file['file'] );
      $name = $file['filename'];
      $type = $file['type'];
      $title = $t ? $t : $name;
      $content = $c;

      $attachment = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_parent' => $pid,
        'post_mime_type' => $type,
        'guid' => $file['url'],
      );

      foreach( get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $s ) {
        $sizes[$s] = array( 'width' => '', 'height' => '', 'crop' => true );
        $sizes[$s]['width'] = get_option( "{$s}_size_w" ); // For default sizes set in options
        $sizes[$s]['height'] = get_option( "{$s}_size_h" ); // For default sizes set in options
        $sizes[$s]['crop'] = get_option( "{$s}_crop" ); // For default sizes set in options
      }

      $sizes = apply_filters( 'intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', $sizes );

      foreach( $sizes as $size => $size_data ) {
        $resized = image_make_intermediate_size( $file['file'], $size_data['width'], $size_data['height'], $size_data['crop'] );
        if ( $resized )
          $metadata['sizes'][$size] = $resized;
      }

      $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file['file'] /*, $pid - for post_thumbnails*/);

      if ( !is_wp_error( $id )) {
        $attach_meta = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file['file'] );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_meta );
      }

      return array(
        'pid' =>$pid,
        'url' =>$file['url']
      );
      // update_post_meta( $pid, 'a_image', $file['url'] );
    }
  }
}
```

and then I used the following code:

- to create a post and then
- upload then use `my_update_attachment` to process the image
- and finally update the advanced custom field

The code:

```
$args= array(   'post_type' => 'watches',       'post_status' => 'publish'    );

$watch = wp_insert_post($args);
$att = my_update_attachment('watch_image',$watch);
update_field('field_512e085a9372a',$att['url'],$watch);
```

What am I missing? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you use the update_field() part? was that in a function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same problem, you almost had it right, which helped me as well.

looked at ACF and the `update_field` accepts attachment ID as oppose to the the, `pid` or `url`

You can replace the return array:

```
return array(
    'pid' =>$pid,
    'url' =>$file['url']
);
```

With the following array:

```
return array(
  'pid' =>$pid,
  'url' =>$file['url'],
  'file'=>$file,
  'attach_id'=>$attach_id
);
```

and then change

```
update_field('field_512e085a9372a',$att['url'],$watch);
```

with the following

```
update_field('field_512e085a9372a',$att['attach_id'],$watch);
```

Comment: that blog link is spam, dont click

Comment: @NateBeers Cheers, I have removed the link

Answer (score 0):

should this line
    `if ( !is_wp_error( $id )) {`

be 
    `if ( !is_wp_error( $attach_id )) {`

Answer (score -5):

Check this plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-frontend-display/

1. Create ACF form with frontendUploader field (plugin extention)
2. Add your ACF form into post and with post admin panel use checkbox to view on front

Comment: Your plugin doesn't seem to work with ACF V5. So, it's not really a solution.